# How to increase and decrease values on button clicking?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement an increase and decrease on button click. But I cannot figure out how to do that. I have tried to declare to increase and decrease its value by using a button, but that didn't work. Anyone help...

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please edit your answer and add some code so that we can get enough insight of the problem . Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is one of the first thing you can see in react documentation. Please do some search before asking question https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### How to increase and decrease values on button click ?

Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const handleAdd=()=>{
    setCounter(counter+1)
  }
  const handleSub=()=>{
    setCounter(counter-1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add 1</button>
      <button onClick={handleSub}>Subtract 1</button>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a Sandbox for you to try:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-fire-oeozl2?file=/src/App.js